# Preorder on real-valued random variables

Tags: probability

We say that $X$ is smaller than $Y$ in distribution (which we denote by $X \stackrel{D}{<} Y$) if $\mathbb{E}[h(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[h(Y)]$ for all positive, increasing and bounded functions $h$.

We say that $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution (which we denote by $X \stackrel{D}{\sim} Y$) if $X \stackrel{D}{<} Y$ and $Y \stackrel{D}{<} X$

I've already answered the following question :

> 1. Prove that $X \stackrel{D}{<} Y$ if and only if the cumulative
>      distribution functions $F$ and $G$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively
>      satisfy $F \geq G$

Indeed, it suffices to take $h(x) = 1\!\!1_{x \geq c}$ for different values of $c$.

But I don't know how to answer the following two questions :

> 2. Prove that $X \stackrel{D}{<} Y$  if and only if we can find two random variables $X'$ and $Y'$ such that $X \stackrel{D}{\sim} X'$, $Y \stackrel{D}{\sim} Y'$ and $X' \leq Y'$ a.s.
> 3. Suppose that $X \leq Y$ a.s. and $X \stackrel{D}{\sim} Y$. Prove that $X = Y$ a.s.

Can I have some help on these two questions ?

Answer (score 1):

For 3 we are assuming $X,Y$ lie on the same space, say $\Omega$. Since these variables are real-valued, $Y(\omega)>X(\omega)$ implies there is some $q\in\mathbb{Q},n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $Y>q+1/n,X<q-1/n$ when $n>n_0$. So 
$$
P\{X<Y\}\le P(\cup_{q,n_0}\cap_{n>n_0}\{Y>q+1/n,X<q-1/n\})\le \sum_{q,n_0}P(\cap_{n>n_0}\{Y>q+1/n\text{ and }X<q-1/n\})=\sum_{q,n_0}P(Y>q\text{ and }X<q)=\sum_{q,n_0}(P(Y>q)-P(X>q))=0.
$$
In the first equality I used that $\cap_{n>n_0}\{Y>q+1/n,X<q-1/n\})\uparrow\{Y>q,X<q\}$ as $n_0\to\infty$, for the second equality I used that $X<Y$ a.s., and for the last equality I used $Y\sim X$.

For 2 the skorokhod representation might do the trick. Speaking loosely, given a cdf $F$, flip the $x$ and $y$ axes, giving you a variable $Z$ defined on the unit interval with lesbesgue measure such that the cdf of $Z$ is $F$ (you need to handle details like where $F$ is constant). So let $X',Y'$ be the skorokhod representations of $X,Y$, then $X',Y'$ have the same distributions as $X,Y$, then by 1 they are equivalent under the pre-ordering to $X,Y$ (respectively). Also by 1, $F_{X}\ge F_{Y}$, so when you "flip" the axes to get the skorokhod representations, $Y'>X'$ a.s.

Comment: Thanks for 2 and 3. For 3, I think that you have to change some "<" to "$\leq$" (and ">" to "$\geq$") but I got the idea. For 2, it seems OK but I'm waiting for a more elementary solution.